# Crop Image with face detection in android

Tags: android, crop, geometry, face-detection

I needed a demo where any image can be cropped with the face detection function.

**FIXED**

But after few surfing hours I didn't come to a single demo, so I prepared a single demo with conjunction of few demos that I found online.

I have prepared a demo to crop the image.

My demo crops the image rectangle, and circular as well.

Also it detects the face and crops the image according to the face detection.

I am using the following image to crop it.

[image: main image]

And the screenshot of the crop result is :

[image: Screenshot]

The xml for the example is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/part1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >
</View>

<View
    android:id="@+id/part2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >
</View>

</LinearLayout>
```

The java code for the Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public View part1, part2;
int viewHeight, viewWidth;
private FaceDetector myFaceDetect;
private FaceDetector.Face[] myFace;
float myEyesDistance;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    part1 = findViewById(R.id.part1);
    part2 = findViewById(R.id.part2);
    part1.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewHeight = part1.getMeasuredHeight();
            viewWidth = part1.getMeasuredWidth();
            try {

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(),
                        R.drawable.sachin_tendulkar_10102013);

                int targetWidth = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
                int targetHeight = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

                Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                        targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
                Path path = new Path();

                path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.clipPath(path);

                canvas.drawBitmap(
                        bitmapOrg,
                        new Rect(0, 0, bitmapOrg.getWidth(), bitmapOrg
                                .getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                                targetHeight), paint);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(1f, 1f);

                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.sachin_tendulkar_10102013,
                        bitmapFatoryOptions);

                myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[5];
                myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(targetWidth, targetHeight,
                        5);
                int numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(
                        bitmapOrg, myFace);
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
                if (numberOfFaceDetected > 0) {
                    PointF myMidPoint = null;
                    Face face = myFace[0];
                    myMidPoint = new PointF();
                    face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
                    myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();

                    if (myMidPoint.x + viewWidth > targetWidth) {
                        while (myMidPoint.x + viewWidth > targetWidth) {
                            myMidPoint.x--;
                        }
                    }
                    if (myMidPoint.y + viewHeight > targetHeight) {
                        while (myMidPoint.y + viewHeight > targetHeight) {
                            myMidPoint.y--;
                        }
                    }
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg,
                            (int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance),
                            (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                            viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                } else {
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                            viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                }
                /* convert Bitmap to resource */
                // Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBitmap,
                // 0,
                // 0, viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

                part1.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error1 : " + e.getMessage()
                        + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    part2.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewHeight = part2.getMeasuredHeight();
            viewWidth = part2.getMeasuredWidth();
            try {

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(),
                        R.drawable.sachin_tendulkar_10102013);

                int targetWidth = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
                int targetHeight = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

                Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                        targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
                Path path = new Path();

                path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.clipPath(path);

                canvas.drawBitmap(
                        bitmapOrg,
                        new Rect(0, 0, bitmapOrg.getWidth(), bitmapOrg
                                .getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                                targetHeight), paint);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(1f, 1f);

                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.sachin_tendulkar_10102013,
                        bitmapFatoryOptions);

                myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[5];
                myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(targetWidth, targetHeight,
                        5);
                int numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(
                        bitmapOrg, myFace);
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
                if (numberOfFaceDetected > 0) {
                    PointF myMidPoint = null;
                    Face face = myFace[0];
                    myMidPoint = new PointF();
                    face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
                    myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance() + 20;

                    if (myMidPoint.x + viewWidth > targetWidth) {
                        while (myMidPoint.x + viewWidth > targetWidth) {
                            myMidPoint.x--;
                        }
                    }
                    if (myMidPoint.y + viewHeight > targetHeight) {
                        while (myMidPoint.y + viewHeight > targetHeight) {
                            myMidPoint.y--;
                        }
                    }
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg,
                            (int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance),
                            (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance),
                            viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                } else {
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                            viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                }
                /* convert Bitmap to resource */
                // Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBitmap,
                // 0,
                // 0, viewWidth, viewHeight, matrix, true);
                BitmapDrawable bd = new  BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

                part2.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(
                        getCroppedBitmap(bd.getBitmap())));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error1 : " + e.getMessage()
                        + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    // bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    //
    // final int color = 0xff424242;
    // final Paint paint = new Paint();
    // final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
    // bitmap.getHeight());
    //
    // paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    // canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // paint.setColor(color);
    // // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    // canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
    // bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    // paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    // // Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    // // return _bmp;
    // return output;

    int targetWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int targetHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) /    2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = bitmap;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
            sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
            targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;

}

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem now ?

Comment: My issues are solved now, but uploaded the code in case anyone wants it, thnx..

Comment: Is it working in any image ?

Comment: Yes it is..you just have to put image in any drawable folder like i did..also if you want to crop any image from gallery, just make a bitmap named bitmapOrg of that image..and continue with the demo..

Comment: it is not working with all images

Comment: Well, it really depends on how visible the faces are in the image, if it can detect the face shape from image, it works, still if you find any issues, please provide more info about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879294/image-crop-multiple-faces-and-save-faces-in-list-view-in-andriod 
priyank joshi kindly help me out if u can :)

Comment: @PriyankJoshi what is the library you are using to detect the face?

Comment: which library do you use for Face detection?

Comment: No 3rd party lib is used in this demo, its the google api com.google.android.gms.vision.face which is accessible to developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo works for any image put in the drawable folder,

But if you want to crop any dynamic image, for example any image which is downloaded or chosen from gallery, make few changes in the code :

See the line :

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(),
                    R.drawable.sachin_tendulkar_10102013);
```

Here I am taking the image from the drawable folder, now for any downloaded image, you just need to save that image in the bitmapOrg variable, so just change the above line twice, one for part1 for rectangle and part2 for ciculart with your downloaded image saving to bitmapOrg as bitmap, and use the demo, it will crop your image in rectangle and circular way.

Comment: i am used this but it is not give 100% result in every image. if u used new google vision api with the classification then it's give u 100%.