# How to Crop only face from an image in android?

Tags: android, face-detection

I got a requirement to display only face from an image. But, I am trying to use only android native methods to implement this.

I have gone through the following link

[Crop Image with face detection in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552027/crop-image-with-face-detection-in-android)

But, the code mentioned in the above link is not working for all images.

Please guide me if anyone has already got the same requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does the face detection fail, or does it not extract a circle correctly?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to contain your code, including examples where it worked and where it didn't and error messages if there were any.

Comment: @GVS: Hi, I have used the code I have mentioned in the link, But the code is working only for some images and It is not working for Image containing more than 1 face.

Comment: @Noich: Hi Noich, I have used the same code mentioned in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552027/crop-image-with-face-detection-in-android

Answer (score 0):

A face detection algorithm is never (and will never be) accurate. Even humans sometimes see the face of jezus in a toast. How can you expect computers to detect a face 100% correctly, if even the reference implementation (the human brain) contains bugs.

You should include a fallback scenario, when there is no (or more as one) face detected. Or do some quality check on the pictures before they are used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this rounded rectangle code with bigger corner radius to achieve a circle ([recipe by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)):

```
BitmapShader shader;
shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setShader(shader);

RectF rect = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);

// rect contains the bounds of the shape
// radius is the radius in pixels of the rounded corners
// paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
```

Comment: Hi Eran, Thanks for your reply, I have no problem in displaying bitmap in a circle. I am not able to detect only face from the image. Face detection part I need help, to convert only face to bitmap.

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the question as what you're actually asking is not clear.