# Crop Face From Image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I got a requirement to display only face from an image. I am trying to use only android native methods to implement this.

I can detect face from Image using the following code :

```
public void detectFaces() {
        Log.d("FaceDet", "Detecting faces....");
        // Convert bitmap in 556

        Bitmap tmpBmp = image.copy(Config.RGB_565, true); 

        FaceDetector faceDet = new FaceDetector(tmpBmp.getWidth(), tmpBmp.getHeight(), MAX_FACES);

        Face[] faceList = new Face[MAX_FACES];

        faceDet.findFaces(tmpBmp, faceList);

        Log.d("FaceDetLength", "Face ["+faceList.length+"]");
        // Log the result
        for (int i=0; i < faceList.length; i++) {
            Face face = faceList[i];
            Log.d("FaceDet", "Face ["+face+"]");
            if (face != null) {
                Log.d("FaceDet", "Face ["+i+"] - Confidence ["+face.confidence()+"]");
                PointF pf = new PointF();
                face.getMidPoint(pf);
                Log.d("FaceDet", "\t Eyes distance ["+face.eyesDistance()+"] - Face midpoint ["+pf+"]");
                RectF r = new RectF();
                r.left = pf.x - face.eyesDistance() / 2;
                r.right = pf.x + face.eyesDistance() / 2;
                r.top = pf.y - face.eyesDistance() / 2;
                r.bottom = pf.y + face.eyesDistance() / 2;
                rects[i] = r;
            }
        }

        this.invalidate();
    }
```

Now I want to crop only face from this image. How can I do this ? I have gone through the following link :

[Crop Image with face detection in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552027/crop-image-with-face-detection-in-android)

But, the code mentioned in the above link is not working for all images. How can I crop only faces from Image ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: Check that link to implement correctly `Face recognition`, http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Comment: That link works correctly for any image in drawable folder but not works for image of gallery .

Comment: I need to implement this in Android . No C/C++ code is needed .

Comment: I said in Android, but... maybe you need convert the gallery image to another format?

Comment: I convert it in bitmap . DO I need another format ?

Comment: When you use a image from `Drawable` what format you use? try to put an `bitmap` inside drawable folder and try again with that image

Comment: I pick image from Gallery . How can I put it in to drawable folder ?

Comment: Put it on drawable folder using `Android Studio`

Comment: I pick image from Gallery using Image Picker  in run time . How can I put iit in to drawable folder ?

Comment: omg... try using another `bitmat image` inside drawable folder. It's easy, u said me "works correctly for any image in drawable folder", then... to test if the format, put a bitmap inside drawable folder, if it's works is not the format, if is not works is the image format

Comment: I have put a jpg image in drawable folder . It works . But it does not work for image picked from the gallery .

Comment: Put `A BITMAP` inside drawable folder, not an JPG and try it again

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola library to get cropped faces from bitmap image